# How can I pause music coming from another app in my own app?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm very new to xcode and am trying to figure out how I can pause music coming in from another app such as iTunes or Spotify so that it does not run in the background of my app. Is there a command I'm missing or do I have to have a button to shut it off?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no sign of prior research

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You have to create an audio session with category `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`.